# Show text on slide 2 and then leave that

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am unable to find a way to do this using only or onslide. Please let me know if there is a way. I will try to explain what I want.

I want my 3rd slide to have two images : Image A and Image C exactly below it.
However the Image A must be on all the 3 slides : in the exact same position. Additionally the second slide should have Image B right below Image A.

So 1st slide will have Image A, second slide will have Image A at the same position, Image B right below it and then the third slide should have Image A in the same position and Image B needs to disappear and Image C will arrive, starting at the same position.

I have tried :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{try}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Slide}
    Text 1\\
    \onslide<2->{
    \only<2>{Text 2\\}
    \only<3>{Text 3}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However it doesn't work : the first slide has Image A in the middle, and then moves up. Note that the images are of different sizes.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I've tried doing that. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to top-align your frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}%
  
  \includegraphics<2>[width=1cm]{example-image-b}%
  \includegraphics<3>[width=4cm]{example-image-c}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want a top aligned frame, you could use the `overlayarea` environment. Just make sure that the height you choose is equal (or larger) than your tallest image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
  
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{4cm}
    \includegraphics<2>[width=1cm]{example-image-b}
    \includegraphics<3>[width=4cm]{example-image-c}
  \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, that was super smart and indeed solves my problem. However, is there a way to do it without top align?? For future references

Comment: @UserNotFound See my updated answer

Comment: Ok, to be honest, I was planning on using it for \begin{theorem} , \begin<claim} and things like that instead of images... This seems to be specific to images. I will spend some trying to do this for theorem or claim environments

Comment: No, it is not specific to images. You can have anything in the overlayarea

Comment: For images it is a bit easy since you know the image height, however for arbitrary objects, I am not sure what height I should put

Comment: @UserNotFound Start with a small height, then you will get an overfull box warning in the log file and you'll know exactly how much you need to increase the height. Or just make it "big enough" - it does not hurt if the value is a bit bigger than necessary. (that's why I would always use the 1st approach)

Comment: Thanks, I got it done! Will be my first presentation in a conference. You have been super helpful!!

Comment: @UserNotFound You're welcome! And good luck for your presentation!